# How Does Unix Interpret $?

Tags: centos, users, root, useradd, multiuser

```
[orca@orcacomputers public_html]$ adduser Jé$$è+rèè
adduser: invalid user name 'Jé28956è+rèè'
```

I am unable to use $ when adding users in CentOS7.  Karen goes "WHY THE HELL WOULD YOU DO THAT!?" as she socially crucifies me as I am being my authentic self with is a Left Handed Neanderthal.  Curiosity.

I am an auditor by trade so I increase my levels of happiness when I curate data.  So what is $ telling unix here? What I can is so far is `$$=28956` in unix.  Is this a random string?

Are there any ways to use the `$` character to sort data? or any other usecase that would be deemed productive for Computer Science purposes?

```
[orca@orcacomputers public_html]$ adduser Jéssè+rèè
adduser: invalid user name 'Jéssè+rèè'
```

What really!? Is this where I have to make my own distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to BlueManCZ's answer on how to escape special characters, the username you are proposing contains many invalid characters. Please refer to CentOS 7's man page for adduser, under the CAVEATS section:

```
CAVEATS
       You may not add a user to a NIS or LDAP group. This must be performed on the corresponding
       server.

       Similarly, if the username already exists in an external user database such as NIS or LDAP,
       useradd will deny the user account creation request.

       Usernames may contain only lower and upper case letters, digits, underscores, or dashes. They
       can end with a dollar sign. Dashes are not allowed at the beginning of the username. Fully
       numeric usernames and usernames . or .. are also disallowed. It is not recommended to use
       usernames beginning with . character as their home directories will be hidden in the ls
       output. In regular expression terms: [a-zA-Z0-9_.][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*[$]?
```

You may find an online copy of the man page [here](https://manpath.be/c7/8/adduser). So while `$` is a valid character in a username, it is only valid at the end. Additionally `+` and letters with accents e.g. `è` are never valid in CentOS' implementation of adduser.

And yes, if you do not like it you are free to roll your own. You may find the source code [here](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/useradd.c).

Answer (score 4):

The shell interprets `$` as a special character. `$$` in your case returns the PID of your current shell. If you want to use `$` in a string, you have to escape it with backslash `\$`.

For example:

```
echo Jé\$\$è+rèè

Jé$$è+rèè
```